# call methods asynchronously or do post and call methods without waiting for results

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I need to call two methods which will take time to execute but i do not need to wait for results.

So, somebody suggests me to call those methods asynchronously OR do post and execute those methods.

I did research and found that calling methods asynchronously, which might sometimes consumes a lot of memory.

Please suggest me a better way.

Thanks

Comment: You can use Threads for your goal, or BackgroundWorker.

Comment: If you want features to fit your convenience, they will cost memory. As you only need to make 2 calls, the memory overhead should not cause problems.

Comment: @MrFox, memory is not a problem but just want to know a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issue.
I used `jQuery ajax` with `generic http handler` returing `json`
I created handler and put my business logic there.
It return me the result in form of `json`
I iterated the `json` using jquery.
And created my html form that.

### Edit 1

Here are some useful links
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/203621/Call-HTTPhandler-from-jQuery-Pass-data-and-retriev

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/11/sp2010-ajax-part-4-returning-json-from.html

### Edit 2

You can also take benefit of jtemplate
http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/01/05/using-the-jtemplate-jquery-plugin-with-ajax-and-asp-net/

http://encosia.com/use-jquery-and-aspnet-ajax-to-build-a-client-side-repeater/